# Bad Compile constant value

Tags: c#

I get "Bad Compile constant value" on this statement.

```
Regex objCheckNumber = new Regex("^(\d){4}$");
```

I simply want to set this up to check another string to see if the value entered is 4 digits.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

C# is trying to interpret `\d` as an escape sequence, and `\d` is *not* a valid escape sequence (but `\n` and `\t` are, for example). You can either double up the backslashes to escape it (`"^(\\d){4}$"`), or you can prefix the constant string with an at-sign: `@"^(\d){4}$"`.

Comment: thanks, completely overlooked it probably because I was thinking too much about the regex and it's a string duh.

Comment: whoops, did not mean to up psasiks comment.

Comment: @psasik: Obviously `\d` holds meaning within a regular expression, but it does **not** hold meaning within a normal string.  As an input to a regular expression, `\d` is two characters, whereas in a normal string, `\n` and `\t` get interpreted as **one** character.

Comment: Don't worry, Mark Some of us are paying attention tonight.

Answer (score 8):

C# uses \ as an escape character. You need to double up the `\` to `\\`.

Alternatively, place a @ character before the double-quote:

```
new Regex(@"^(\d){4}$")
```

Comment: The \ escapes the d which means single numeric character. With {4} he's looking for four of them in a row.

Comment: @pasasik - yes, \d has special meaning to the regex engine, but you have to get that string to the regex engine first.  Without doubling it or using @, the C# compiler thinks you mean \d as a 'special' character (like \t or \n) and tries (and fails) to handle it.

Comment: i am testing in RegexHero: http://regexhero.net/tester/ and ... jeesh. i see my mistake. (Sorry about the downvote binarycoder, SO wouldn't let me reverse it...)